# How can I turn a chess FEN into a PGN?

Tags: r, chess

I have a series of FEN strings and accompanying moves in LAN (Long Algebraic Notation) that look like the below. An example dataframe is pasted at the end of my question.

| FEN | Moves | GameUrl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| r3k2r/1b1pbppp/p7/1pp5/3q4/P1NPBp1P/1PP1B1P1/R4Q1K w kq - 0 19 | e3d4 f3g2 f1g2 b7g2 h1g2 c5d4 | [Link](https://lichess.org/6OEDg4W3#Some(36)) |
| 3rr1k1/5ppp/6q1/pp6/1bppPn2/5P2/PPP2QPP/2NRBRK1 w - - 8 25 | e1b4 f4h3 g1h1 h3f2 | [Link](https://lichess.org/W9LaAFV1#Some(48)) |
| r1bq1rk1/ppp2ppp/2np1b1n/3Q2N1/2B1PP2/4B3/PP2N1PP/R4RK1 b - - 0 13 | h6g4 g5f7 f8f7 d5f7 | [Link](https://lichess.org/BxbS4jtt/black#Some(25)) |

Each row in this dataframe is a chess puzzle. I would like to generate a PGN of the puzzle, based on the initial FEN and then applying the sequence of moves that make up the puzzle, currently stored in `Moves` in Long Algebraic Notation.

So my ideal result for the first line of the above dataframe would be:

| FEN | Moves | GameUrl | PGN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r3k2r/1b1pbppp/p7/1pp5/3q4/P1NPBp1P/1PP1B1P1/R4Q1K w kq - 0 19 | e3d4 f3g2 f1g2 b7g2 h1g2 c5d4 | [Link](https://lichess.org/6OEDg4W3#Some(36)) | [Variant "From Position"][FEN "r3k2r/1b1pbppp/p7/1pp5/3q4/P1NPBp1P/1PP1B1P1/R4Q1K w kq - 0 19"]19. Bxd4 fxg2+ 20. Qxg2 Bxg2+ 21. Kxg2 cxd4 |

To achieve this we need to convert the LAN moves into SAN (Short Algebraic Notation).

Using R's `bigchess` package I tried to turn the moves to SAN as below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(bigchess)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Moves_SAN = sapply(Moves, lan2san))
```

But I think it's reading the `Moves` as being from the starting position of a chess board and so the translated `Moves_SAN` are incorrect.

**Does anyone know a way to convert the LAN to SAN based on the FEN and using an available package in R?**

I am imagining the solution involves loading the FEN with `bigchess`, `stockfish` or `chess` and then applying the LAN and somehow translating them into SAN with this context, but I haven't been able to work out how.

```
structure(list(FEN = c("r3k2r/1b1pbppp/p7/1pp5/3q4/P1NPBp1P/1PP1B1P1/R4Q1K w kq - 0 19", 
"3rr1k1/5ppp/6q1/pp6/1bppPn2/5P2/PPP2QPP/2NRBRK1 w - - 8 25", 
"r1bq1rk1/ppp2ppp/2np1b1n/3Q2N1/2B1PP2/4B3/PP2N1PP/R4RK1 b - - 0 13"
), Moves = c("e3d4 f3g2 f1g2 b7g2 h1g2 c5d4", "e1b4 f4h3 g1h1 h3f2", 
"h6g4 g5f7 f8f7 d5f7"), GameUrl = c("https://lichess.org/6OEDg4W3#Some(36)", 
"https://lichess.org/W9LaAFV1#Some(48)", "https://lichess.org/BxbS4jtt/black#Some(25)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000026e39ef2e30>)
```

Comment: I presume that you want to load the FEN position and then generate classical chess notation SAN <piece><destination_square> or <piece>x<piece> instead of computer move notation <from_square><to_square>.  You must load the FEN position first and then follow the move chain from there. The initial default board starting position will give nonsense - you must load the FEN position first!

Comment: Yes that makes sense, and I mentioned a bit of that in the last section of the question. A challenge is that I can't find a method of achieving this based on existing chess packages in R (bigchess, rchess, stockfish, chess).

Comment: This can be done easily with python. Let me check with R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R really deserves a more complete package implementing chess stuff independently of engines.  I suspect that Python does much better here.  Well, here are some wrappers around **bigchess** that should do what you want for *valid* FEN and LAN movetext ...

```r
read.pos <- function(pos) {
    map <- list("P" =  1L, "B" =  2L, "N" =  3L, "R" =  4L, "Q" =  5L, "K" =  6L,
                "p" = -1L, "b" = -2L, "n" = -3L, "r" = -4L, "q" = -5L, "k" = -6L)
    map <- c(map, setNames(lapply(0:8, integer), c("/", 1:8)))
    matrix(unlist(map[strsplit(pos, "")[[1L]]], FALSE, FALSE),
           nrow = 8L, ncol = 8L, byrow = TRUE,
           dimnames = list(8:1, letters[1:8]))
}

fenlan2san <- function(fen, lan) {
    lan <- strsplit(lan, " ")[[1L]]
    nhm <- length(lan)
    if (nhm == 0L)
        return("")
    fen <- strsplit(fen, " ")[[1L]]
    pos <- read.pos(fen[1L])
    san <- character(nhm)
    for (i in seq_along(lan)) {
        move <- bigchess:::string.lan.move2move(lan[i])
        m1 <- move[1L]; m2 <- move[2L]; m3 <- move[3L]; m4 <- move[4L]; m5 <- move[5L]

        wb <- sign(pos[m1, m2])
        san[i] <- bigchess:::move2san(pos, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5)
        pos <- bigchess:::position.move(pos, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5)
        if (bigchess:::is.check(pos, wb))
            san[i] <- paste0(san[i], if (bigchess:::is.mate(pos, wb)) "#" else "+")
    }
    wtm <- fen[2L] == "w"
    nfm <- (nhm + (if (wtm) 1L else 2L)) %/% 2L
    i1 <- as.integer(fen[6L])
    i2 <- i1 - 1L + nfm
    if (wtm)
        san[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- paste0( i1      :i2, ". ", san[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
    else {
        san[1L] <- paste0(i1, "... ", san[1L])
        if (i1 < i2)
        san[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- paste0((i1 + 1L):i2, ". ", san[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
    }
    paste0(san, collapse = " ")
}

fenlan2pgn <- function(fen, lan)
    paste0("[Variant \"From Position\"] [FEN \"", fen, "\"] ", mapply(fenlan2san, fen, lan))
```

And then:

```r
fen <- c("r3k2r/1b1pbppp/p7/1pp5/3q4/P1NPBp1P/1PP1B1P1/R4Q1K w kq - 0 19",
         "3rr1k1/5ppp/6q1/pp6/1bppPn2/5P2/PPP2QPP/2NRBRK1 w - - 8 25",
         "r1bq1rk1/ppp2ppp/2np1b1n/3Q2N1/2B1PP2/4B3/PP2N1PP/R4RK1 b - - 0 13")
lan <- c("e3d4 f3g2 f1g2 b7g2 h1g2 c5d4",
         "e1b4 f4h3 g1h1 h3f2",
         "h6g4 g5f7 f8f7 d5f7")
writeLines(fenlan2pgn(fen, lan))
```

```
[Variant "From Position"] [FEN "r3k2r/1b1pbppp/p7/1pp5/3q4/P1NPBp1P/1PP1B1P1/R4Q1K w kq - 0 19"] 19. Bxd4 fxg2+ 20. Qxg2 Bxg2+ 21. Kxg2 cxd4
[Variant "From Position"] [FEN "3rr1k1/5ppp/6q1/pp6/1bppPn2/5P2/PPP2QPP/2NRBRK1 w - - 8 25"] 25. Bxb4 Nh3+ 26. Kh1 Nxf2+
[Variant "From Position"] [FEN "r1bq1rk1/ppp2ppp/2np1b1n/3Q2N1/2B1PP2/4B3/PP2N1PP/R4RK1 b - - 0 13"] 13... Ng4 14. Nxf7 Rxf7 15. Qxf7+
```

Importing each PGN to the Lichess analysis board suggests that it's working OK: https://lichess.org/analysis

But my feeling is that someone familiar with **stockfish** and the UCI protocol could get the same result in a much nicer way ...